# OpenGL 4.4 texture atlas artifacts

Tags: opengl, tile, artifacts, texture-atlas

I am writing a small OpenGL tile map renderer in C# with OpenTK.
To render the tiles I first create a vertex array and then a vertex buffer.
At next I iterate over all tiles and dependent from the tile type I add two triangles to the vertex buffer with the corresponding vertices(texture coords, color, position).
To avoid texture expensive switching I use one big texture with all tile textures named texture atlas. 
But I have a problem while working with a texture atlas.
The problem is that I get some artifacts at the edge of some tiles if I zooming out and moving the camera around.
The solutions I found on the internet were...

1. ...to calculate texture coords with half pixel correction.
2. ...to use a texture array

The first one I tried but it didn't worked how expected (More explained below).
The second one I don't know how to work with texture arrays and I couldn't find much about texture arrays on the internet.

I used the following texture filters:

```
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
```

Texture coords calculation **with** half pixel correction:

```
text_coord_x = (0.5f + pixel_x) / texture_width;
text_coord_y = (0.5f + pixel_x) / texture_height;
```

Texture coords calculation **without** half pixel correction:

```
text_coord_x = pixel_x / texture_width;
text_coord_y = pixel_y / texture_height;
```

One tile **with** half pixel correction:
[image: One tile with half pixel correction]

One tile **without** half pixel correction:
[image: One tile without half pixel correction]

Multiple tiles **with** half pixel correction:
[image: Multiple tiles with half pixel correction]

Multiple tiles **without** half pixel correction:
[image: Multiple tiles without half pixel correction]

Answer (score 1):

For solve your problem with border at atlas you should left N pixel border around each sprite. This border should contain pixel information depends of tiling what you need. This border may be generated by lot 3d programs.

For example Blender can bake several textures into one with margin options:

[image]

Also N pixels width depends from mip levels of future atlas. So if you will add one pixel border then you can to use only single mip level (zero mip level). For two - you can use 0 mip and 1 mip level etc. Make sure that your use mip levels not more them border width was.

Comment: Thanks this would be a solution I have to probably to use but is there no better way ? For example the minecraft tileset file contains no borders and in the game there seems to be no artifacts. Know someone how this was fixed ?

Comment: Could you describe your case detailed? What you wanna make?

Comment: I wonder me how minecraft use a texture atlas without borders or paddings without any artifacts in game.

Comment: Minecraft use Nearest like your sample. At this case they can use centroid interpolation for avoid extrapolation (look here https://www.opengl.org/pipeline/article/vol003_6/ ) or clamp texture coordinates in fragment shader by real sprite coordinate at atlas. But all of this will looks bad if texture will downsampled.